# Set $G=\{C\subset\mathbb{R}^n\}$. Is there a binary operation $\cdot$ such that $(G,\cdot)$ is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Set $G=\{C\subset\mathbb{R}^n\}$. Is there a binary operation $\cdot$ such that $(G,\cdot)$ is a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition)?

The biggest trouble I'm having is concerning the existence of inverses. A standard notion of "set addition" is [Minkowski addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition), but this does not have inverses in general.

For those interested, I have asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432828/is-there-a-normed-vector-space-of-shapes) on this concerning the Hausdorff distance (also still unresolved).

Comment: If you accept the axiom of choice, any set has an operation that turns it into a group. It might not be a meaningful one, but then one has to define what "meaningful" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, consider the operation $\Delta$ of symmetric difference given by

$$A\Delta B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B).$$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

But even more abstractly, take any group $H$ of size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ and a bijection $f : G \to H$. Then you can "transport" the structure from $H$ to $G$ so that $G$ becomes a group isomorphic to $H$.